# I have a page with two domains and I want to redirect one of the domains to a specific page via htaccess

Tags: domains, htaccess, redirects

I am using the domains `ergonomi.example` and `fysiarbejdsliv.example`

I want `fysiarbejdsliv.example` to redirect to `https://fysiarbejdsliv.example/dansk-selskab-for-fysioterapi-i-arbejdsliv`.

I have tried a lot of solutions in htaccess, but none of them are working for me.

Like:

```
RewriteRule ^fysiarbejdsliv.example/(.*)$ https://www.fysiarbejdsliv.example/dansk-selskab-for-fysioterapi-i-arbejdsliv/$1 [L,R=301,QSA]
```

Both `ergonomi.example` and `fysiarbejdsliv.example` points to the homepage as it is now. I want `fysiarbejdsliv.example` to redirect to `https://www.fysiarbejdsliv.example/dansk-selskab-for-fysioterapi-i-arbejdsliv`. Is this possible?

Comment: How is the DNS for the domains set up?  Do both domains currently point to the same server?   How are the virtual hosts for the domains set up?  Are they both `ServerName` or `ServerAlias` to the same `DocumentRoot`?

Comment: “None of them are working for me” - please state specifically what the problem is. In what way are they not working? Do you get an error? Nothing happens? Do both domains redirect? Do you have other directives?

Comment: When I write “None of them are working for me” I mean there is no redirection at all: fysiarbejdsliv.example simply ends up on fysiarbejdsliv.example.

As it is now both domains point to the same server. When the domains change only the url's change.

I want ergonomi.example to remain as the frontpage when users use ergonomi.example and when users use fysiarbejdsliv.example I want to redirect to https://www.fysiarbejdsliv.example/dansk-selskab-for-fysioterapi-i-arbejdsliv

Best regards

Pelle

Comment: I re-edited this for you to include the URL and code formatting, and generic domains.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^fysiarbejdsliv.example/(.*)$ https://www.fysiarbejdsliv.example/dansk-selskab-for-fysioterapi-i-arbejdsliv/$1 [L,R=301,QSA]
> ```

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* (first argument) matches against the URL-path only - this does not include the *hostname*. So the above directive will simply never match the request and will do nothing.

However, with this directive it looks like you are trying to do something very different to what you stated in the question. In your question you state that you want to redirect `fysiarbejdsliv.example` (no `www` subdomain?) to `https://fysiarbejdsliv.example/dansk-selskab-for-fysioterapi-i-arbejdsliv` only. But your directive has a capturing group in the *pattern* and you are using a backreference in the substitution? Is this just a bad case of copy/paste or a suggestion that you are really trying to do something else? This directive looks like you are trying to redirect `fysiarbejdsliv.example/<anything>` to `https://www.fysiarbejdsliv.example/dansk-selskab-for-fysioterapi-i-arbejdsliv/<same-anything>`?

Since both domains point to the same filesystem you will need an additional condition (`RewriteCond` directive) to check the `Host` header (ie. the domain name) before making the redirect.

For example, using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} \bfysiarbejdsliv\.example [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ https://www.fysiarbejdsliv.example/dansk-selskab-for-fysioterapi-i-arbejdsliv [R=302,L]
```

The above redirects `http[s]://[www.]fysiarbejdsliv\.example/` to `https://www.fysiarbejdsliv.example/dansk-selskab-for-fysioterapi-i-arbejdsliv` only.

This needs to go *before* any existing (or rather "conflicting") redirects/rewrites. If you have any mod_alias `Redirect` or `RedirectMatch` directives then these may need rewriting to use mod_rewrite instead.

Make sure you've cleared your browser cache before testing and only change the 302 (temporary) redirect to a 301 (permanent) when you are sure it's working OK to avoid caching issues.

Answer (score 0):

you can do the following 
for external site

```
Redirect /path/to/old/file/old.html http://www.example.com/new/file/new.html
```

for local site

```
Redirect /path/to/old/file/old.html /path/to/new/file/new.html
```

Link to the reference:-

> https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215747748-How-can-I-redirect-and-rewrite-my-URLs-with-an-htaccess-file-

Comment: This doesn’t differentiate between the two domains, which both point to the same site, so both will be redirected.